# Paypal Ipn system confused :S

Tags: php, paypal

i'm trying to integrate paypal ipn in my site
Here's the situation :
All prices will saved in the database
when user select to pay the user will be transfered to paypal (with price given by db) ,after payment i want verify payment if its accurate and then want it to add certain rows in db !
i checked http://cms.paypal.com
but i couldn't get it work .
can anybody explain me ?

Answer (score 0):

For Paypal ipn you need to setup a script which will keep handling requests from paypal server.  Based on these requests you need to further process you order.  Sometimes a order is accepted initially but later declined. You can handle these cases only if you have ipn in place.

For frontend basic payment processing use a simple form or paypal express checkout.

Comment: what exactly are you not getting ? For general overview just google php+paypal+ipn